# Build dex file using gradle

Tags: android, build, gradle, dex

I'm trying to automate my app build process using gradle. One of build step is generating dex files from android libraries projects.

These projects is main app modules and loads in runtime.

In current build process I'm building library's jar and convert it to dex using script. It is done by eclipse build command.

Is there a way and how to do it with gradle?

Answer (score 1):

You need to manually call `dx` eg.

```
task finalize() {
    doFirst {
        println('Encrypting!')
        println("${projectDir}")

        exec {
            workingDir "${projectDir}/build/intermediates/classes/debug"
            commandLine "/home/MyUser/Android/Sdk/build-tools/26.0.0/dx"             \
            , "--dex"             \
            , "--output=my/example/com/secureme/SecuredData.dex"             \
            , "my/example/com/secureme/SecuredData.class"
        }
        //We don't want in our APK this .class
        project.delete "build/intermediates/classes/debug/my/example/com/secureme/SecuredData.class"

        // Encrypt our .dex file
        encrypt.execute()

        copy {
            from "build/intermediates/classes/debug/my/example/com/secureme/SecuredData.dex"
            into "src/main/assets/"
        }
    }
}

tasks.withType(JavaCompile) { compileTask -> compileTask.finalizedBy finalize }
```

Full example [here](https://github.com/gelldur/msc-thesis/blob/master/project/SecureMe/app/build.gradle)