# How to compile android library to dex via gradle cross platform

Tags: android, windows, gradle

In order to compile an android library code to dex file, I run `gradlew` and `d8` in bash.

```bash
./gradlew :assembleRelease
~/Android/Sdk/build-tools/34.0.0/d8 --release --output build build/intermediates/aar_main_jar/release/classes.jar
```

The drawbacks are:

1. the `d8` binary is hardcoded
2. doesn't work on Windows os

I need to overcome these for working with other staff. Writing these as gradle task can drop bash, but I don't know how to find and call d8 correctly. There are some solutions for compiling to dex, but seems not work for Windows:
https://www.bogado.net/android/Build_dex_gradle.html
[Build dex file using gradle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24942276/build-dex-file-using-gradle)